# draw path in OpenStreetMap

Tags: openstreetmap, gpx

I have a GPX file with me. I need to draw a root map using this GPX file with selected points(as stops) OpenStreetMap.

What kind of steps I need to take.

Please help me.
Sample code in GPX file is given below

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
    <gpx version="1.0">
        <name>Example gpx</name>
        <wpt lat="46.57638889" lon="8.89263889">
            <ele>2372</ele>
            <name>LAGORETICO</name>
        </wpt>
        <trk><name>Example gpx</name><number>1</number><trkseg>
            <trkpt lat="46.57608333" lon="8.89241667"><ele>2376</ele><time>2007-10-14T10:09:57Z</time></trkpt>
            <trkpt lat="46.57619444" lon="8.89252778"><ele>2375</ele><time>2007-10-14T10:10:52Z</time></trkpt>
            <trkpt lat="46.57641667" lon="8.89266667"><ele>2372</ele><time>2007-10-14T10:12:39Z</time></trkpt>
            <trkpt lat="46.57650000" lon="8.89280556"><ele>2373</ele><time>2007-10-14T10:13:12Z</time></trkpt>
            <trkpt lat="46.57638889" lon="8.89302778"><ele>2374</ele><time>2007-10-14T10:13:20Z</time></trkpt>
            <trkpt lat="46.57652778" lon="8.89322222"><ele>2375</ele><time>2007-10-14T10:13:48Z</time></trkpt>
            <trkpt lat="46.57661111" lon="8.89344444"><ele>2376</ele><time>2007-10-14T10:14:08Z</time></trkpt>
        </trkseg></trk>
    </gpx>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your question really lacks a lot of information but I assume you want to display your GPX file in a browser.

- For just uploading your GPX file on a website which uses OSM as the underlying map: See [track drawing websites](https://wiki.openstreetmap.org/wiki/Track_drawing_websites) in the OSM wiki.
- For displaying your GPX file on your own server or your local computer: [Choose](http://switch2osm.org/using-tiles/) a JavaScript API, for example [Leaflet](http://switch2osm.org/using-tiles/getting-started-with-leaflet/) or [OpenLayers](http://switch2osm.org/using-tiles/getting-started-with-openlayers/). Then just import your GPX file, the Internet has numerous examples.

Comment: Thank you soooo much.. This is my exact requirement..It is very much apreciatable if you providing me a link for same.

Comment: Sorry, a link for what exactly?

Comment: It's okay.. Done.. Thank you for your exact Guidance..:)